# django create abstractbaseuser model, error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making my personal project.
I'm trying to coding signup function. but not work.
createuser is doing right. but when i runserver, and go signup.html page, input value, always same error. what is wrong with my code?

model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import(BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password=None):

        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an name!'))

        user = self.User(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company= company,
            companycode = companycode,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company = company,
            companycode = companycode,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, verbose_name="이름")
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="아이디")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="회사")
    companycode = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="회사코드")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="생성날짜")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['userid', 'company', 'companycode']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All superusers are staff
        return self.is_superuser

    get_full_name.short_description = _('Full name')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UserManager


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'useraccount/signup.html')

def signup_sign(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['name']
        userid = request.POST['id']
        company = request.POST['company']
        code = request.POST['code']
        account = UserManager.create_user(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company = company,
            companycode = code,
        )
        account.save()
        return render(request, 'useraccount/success.html')
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="test" action="/signup_sign/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        NAME : <input type="text" name="name" > </br>
        ID : <input type="text" name="id" > </br>
        COMPANY: <input type="text" name="company"> </br>
        CODE: <input type="password" name="code"> </br>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

basically baseuser required email, name, last name, first name etc..
but i just want input name, id, company name, company code.
so i crated new model using AbstractBaseUser.

but always this error apper.
error.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup_sign/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'useraccount']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_project/useraccount/views.py", line 25, in signup_sign
    companycode = code,

Exception Type: TypeError at /signup_sign/
Exception Value: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py, this line is incorrect:

```
  account = UserManager.create_user(
      username=username,
      userid = userid,
      company = company,
      companycode = code,
  )
```

You should use `User.objects.create_user`:

```
  account = User.objects.create_user(
      username=username,
      userid = userid,
      company = company,
      companycode = code,
  )
```

Make sure to include `from .models import User` at the top of your file.

The reason why your code did not work is because `create_user` is not a static method, so it can only be called from an instance of UserManager, not its class. `User` has an instance of `UserManager`, created by this snippet: `objects = UserManager()`

Comment: Also, it might be better to call your user model something unique like `MyUser` to avoid confusion or incorrect imports generated by your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

But object = models.Manager() and models.Manager() doesn't have any method "create_user()" so what we should do instead ?
create-user() method doesn't supports more than 4 fields in an document.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this really an answer or rather a comment? If it is a comment then please delete it.